# How do I open a Google Docs file (Docs, Sheets, etc) in Firefox?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-docs, firefox, windows

When I try to open a Google Docs file from my Google Drive folder on my Windows 10 computer, it opens in Firefox in a new tab but it shows:

`{"url": "https://docs.google.com/open?id=xxxxxx", "doc_id": "xxxxx", "email": "xxxx@gmail.com"}`

How do I get it to show the actual Google sheets instead?

1. Here is the Google Drive file:

[image]

2. After double-clicking on the file above, it opens like this:

[image]

3. How can I get it to show the file/sheet like this instead:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The file extensions .gsheet, .gdoc are a special type of file shortcuts intended to be used with the old Google Drive client for Windows. This client is not working anymore.

You might have to write a program to tell Windows when this program opens these files. Since the file shourtcuts are usless if the files aren't shared with the user, IMO instead use Google Drive from the Web or use the current Google Drive client for Windows. It could be downloaded from https://drive.google.com.